# make the stuff at the end of the webpage

Tags: html, css

**it would need css to be at the end of the webpage but i dont know the code to do it** 
make the stuff at the end of the webpage 
contact/faq/tos @imgserv 2017

http://prntscr.com/fnwekr

to be like this > http://prntscr.com/fnwf81

my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>image sharer</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>version 1.0</h2>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
image selector :<input type="file" name="image"><br/><br/>
your imgtxt <input type="text" name="desc"><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>

<a href="/tos" class="bottomLinks">tos</a> <a href="/faq" class="bottomLinks">faq</a> <a href="/contact" class="bottomLinks">contact</a> 
    <span id="footerRight" class="copyright footerFont"><strong>@imgserv 2017 </strong></span>
    </div>




<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    @$desc = $_POST['desc'];


move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"uploads/$image_name");
echo "<img src='uploads/$image_name' width='400' height='250'><br>$desc";





}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a JSFiddle for the result you are looking for. Basically what I did was I created a `footer` tag and with CSS made some rules by giving it `position:absolute;`, `bottom:0;`, `width:100%;` `background:#000;` (so you could see it's appending to the bottom).

Here is a JSFiddle of the result. https://jsfiddle.net/s96smh1u/

Comment: could you fix it with posting the full code in answer question @Jorden1337